# How to set a specific location to a string in C#

Tags: c#

How do I go about getting the info from the computers name and setting that location in a string.

Example*

```
string contents = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\Users\" + Settings.Default.User + "\\Documents\\My vs\\juice.txt");
```

Problem is, I cannot use the Setting.Default.User location because that name constantly changes.

I need that section to be some kind of variable that means the computers name....
I don't wanna just hard code in my computers name either because If I put this on my other computers then obviously the name would change

Comment: you want the path of your system?

Comment: Yea, like the user name under user... i.e C:\users\KEVIN\Documents

Comment: @user3720747 You need user name or computer name. Your comment contradicts with your question.

Comment: So you want the users folder but you cannot use Settings.Default.User because that name constantly changes? Can you clarify what you really want here?

Comment: The Enviroment.UserName class worked everyone. Sorry for having some difficulty explaining the question

Comment: @user3720747: Be aware that Environment.UserName will not give you the MyDocuments folder on every system. It will work on default configurations, but already fails easily on machines that are joined to a domain or whenever the user has changed the location of the folders below their profile folder.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

you are looking for [Environment class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment(v=vs.110).aspx):

you can use [Environment.MachineName Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.machinename(v=vs.110).aspx)

Anyway if you need a special folder path you can use: [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx)

there you can find all the special folder available [Environment.SpecialFolder Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @user3720747 happy to help! if you find my answer usefull please mark it as solution

Comment: I will, Says I have to wait 6 minutes

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Environment.GetFolderPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx) method, e.g.:

```
var folder = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments);
var path = System.IO.Path.Combine(folder, "My vs\\juice.txt");
string contents = File.ReadAllText(path);
```

Comment: That's exactly the way to go. Also because the MyDocuments folder may be located outside the profile folder, e.g. on another drive. Just another comment: when using `Path.Combine` you can simply write `Path.Combine(folder, "My vs", "juice.txt");`.

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for... Environment.MachineName

Answer (score 0):

You want to use Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.MyDocuments) as documented here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.specialfolder(v=vs.110).aspx